# Merge only non null fields from source, leave other fields in target unchanged

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Real data has more columns.  Sample Target table has unique ID field.  Data fields have existing data.  Need to update records but only some fields get updated.

```
-- Original/target table
DECLARE @target TABLE (
    ID      varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    x        int NULL,
    y        int NULL,
    z        int NULL );

INSERT INTO @target (ID, x, y, z)
VALUES ('A1', NULL, 2, 3),
       ('A2', 1, 2, NULL),
       ('C4', 1, 2, 3),
       ('Z5', 1, 2, 3)
       ;

--- Updates needed:
DECLARE @updates TABLE (
    ID      varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    x        int NULL,
    y        int NULL,
    z        int NULL );

INSERT INTO @updates (ID, x, y, z)
VALUES ('A1', NULL , 101, NULL),
       ('A2', 201, NULL, NULL),
       ('C4', NULL, NULL, 40),
       ('Z5', NULL, NULL, 99999)
```

I need users to send me data updates that I will use to update /merge into to the target table.  A user may update a specific fields but not other fields.  So when the source table has a value I need it to update the corresponding target field but leave the other fields (that are null in the source) unchanged. Only change a target field if explicitly listed (not null) in the source.

Example, source record with ID=A1 has a updated value for "y" of 101.  After merging, I need the target record for A1 to contain: NULL, 101, 3

I also need a way to "clear" a record in the target.  I thought maybe it would be possible to use a special value for the data like the "99999" shown on record ID Z5.  If the source is "99999" then set target field to NULL.

I will not be adding any records, only matching existing ID's in the target.

UPDATE:

This solution combined from both answers appears to work:

```
update t
    set x = coalesce(u.x, t.x),
        y = coalesce(u.y, t.y),
        z = coalesce(u.z, t.z)
from @target t join
     @updates u
     on t.id = u.id;

update t
    set 
    x = NULLIF(ISNULL(u.x,t.x),'99999'),
    y = NULLIF(ISNULL(u.y,t.y),'99999'),
    z = NULLIF(ISNULL(u.z,t.z),'99999')
from @target t join
     @updates u
     on t.id = u.id;

select * from @target
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  The coalesce worked for the first part and Tab's suggestion worked for the second part.  No way to double credit you both for the help that I see.  Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
update t
    set x = coalesce(u.x, t.x),
        y = coalesce(u.y, t.y),
        z = coalesce(u.z, t.z)
from @target t join
     @updates u
     on t.id = u.id;
```

If you want to clear an entire record, I would recommend adding an additional flag to `@updates`:

```
update t
    set x = (case when u.clear_record = 1 then null
                  when u.x is not null then u.x
                  else t.x
             end),
        y = (case when u.clear_record = 1 then null
                  when u.y is not null then u.y
                  else t.y
             end),
        z = (case when z.clear_record = 1 then null
                  when u.z is not null then u.z
                  else t.z
             end)
from @target t join
     @updates u
     on t.id = u.id;
```

EDIT:

You can clear specific fields by using a special value using similar logic:

```
update t
    set x = (case when u.clear_record = 1 or u.x = '99999' then null
                  when u.x is not null then u.x
                  else t.x
             end),
        y = (case when u.clear_record = 1 or u.y = '9999'9 then null
                  when u.y is not null then u.y
                  else t.y
             end),
        z = (case when z.clear_record = 1 or u.z = '99999' then null
                  when u.z is not null then u.z
                  else t.z
             end)
from @target t join
     @updates u
     on t.id = u.id;
```

However, I would not use `'99999'` for such a special value.  If the values are strings, I would suggest either the empty string (`''`) or `'<null>'` or `'{null}'`.

Comment: I don't think you're handling this requirement:   " If the source is "99999" then set target field to NULL."

Comment: I do not need to clear the entire record, only specific fields.

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . I originally misunderstood the requirement (as applying to the entire record), but I added in logic for it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need:

```
SET Target.Field = NULLIF(ISNULL(Source.Field,Target.Field),'99999')
```

Comment: @shorton, the inner `ISNULL` will select the source value, if one is given, or the target value if the source is null. So if the user passes `99999`, that value will be selected. The outer `NULLIF` will return `NULL` if both arguments are equal to each other. So when the `ISNULL` returns `99999`, the `NULLIF` will  return `NULL`. It's a pretty elegant solution. +1.